# Suppress syntax function help popups in VS Code/VSCodium

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

I'm using VSCodium to write some Python, and using the Python/Intellisense/Pylance Extension and an annoyance is the constant pop-ups explaining every basic function to me.

For example if I start to type a `print()` statement it pops up a large box with all the syntax details of writing a print statement, which blocks my view of much of my code. I'd like to just be able to type without the big pop-up suggestions.

I tried under the Preferences > Settings > text editor and there are pages and pages of "suggest:" option check boxes there, and though I tried several, none helped. Not sure if that's the right place to look.

I tried to change the Quick Suggestions Delay to 5000ms but it seems to have no effect on that instant popup on typing `print(`  as well.

I'm starting to think perhaps there is another set of settings that controls this, but there are so many and none seem to be making a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `editor.quickSuggestions` and `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` turned off for that purpose:

```
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off",
        "other": "off"
    },
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

…and it works for me for languages I am using; not using Python at this point.

Comment: I was about to say it didn't help, but it seems you have to quit and restart after making the settings changes for it to have an effect.  I see I can now type print( without the pop-up – thanks for the suggestion.